# Simple insert into database doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

I have a very simple bit of code to insert data into database.
It doesn't work. I do not get any error except cannot insert. I could connect to the database so that is not the issue.

The database has 3 fields, emailadd is the 2nd field. The other 2 are auto increment id and creation date, so also a field that on add, it will add current timestamp.

```
 $inquiry = "INSERT INTO subscribe (emailadd) VALUES ('$myemail')";
 $res = mysql_query($inquiry) or die("cannot insert");
```

Comment: `mysql_query` is deprecated. You should use `mysqli`. Check [here](http://codular.com/php-mysqli) for an easy tutorial (you'll also end up with an actual error message then).

Comment: You're not getting errors because you're actually not using the proper method. Use `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()` instead of echoing "cannot insert". Also make sure you're not mixing MySQL APIs elsewhere, such as connecting to your DB. That, is unknown to us. Be sure to use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - You now have enough to debug your code. *"doesn't work"* isn't much to go on, nor as a definite reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$inquiry = "INSERT INTO `subscribe` (`emailadd`) VALUES ('$myemail')";
$res = mysql_query($inquiry,$con) or die('Not Inserted : ' . mysql_error());
```

Some time we need $con variable to identify the database connection, let see more check [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: thanks I see now my error is that I do not have permission to insert

Comment: the question is now...how do I add insert permission? the account I use is the only account, I thought...

Comment: @minjiera *"thanks I see now my error is that I do not have permission to insert"* - This obviously doesn't answer the question to the real problem being permissions, and should not have been accepted; it's a falsitude. What you should have done was to update your question with the results you've gotten, then only can the question be something that other people could answer instead in order to actually solve the issue.

Comment: no actually this answer helped me because it wrote out the error. I do not know all the rules of stackoverflow. If i did it wrong, sorry.

Comment: @minjiera [My comment...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28677523/simple-insert-into-database-doesnt-work#comment45648636_28677523) about using `mysql_error()` was posted before this answer. Had you read it, you would have seen what the problem was and would have avoided the question altogether, had you used that in the first place. You said a "permissions" issue. This answer in my view, does not target the specific problem. Anyway, problem solved, great, *carry on.*

Answer (score 0):

the mysql_query is deprecated, you need to use mysqli like so :

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";
```

// Create connection

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

$sql = "UPDATE MyGuests SET lastname='Doe' WHERE id=2";

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

?>
```